# SwipeRefreshLayout disappears after replacing Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, swiperefreshlayout

I have a simple app that contains an Activity(acts as host activity) with two Fragments(FragmentA and FragmentB).
 
There is a SwipeRefreshLayout in the FragmentA. When the SwipeRefreshLayout is refreshing, we replace FragmentA with FragmentB. If we go back to FragmentA(by pressing back button), the SwipeRefreshLayout disappears. For understanding what I mean, please see this image:

[image]

How can I prevent SwipeRefreshLayout from disappearing after replacing the Fragments? My classes are very simple, I just replaced FragmentA with FragmentB
fragment_a.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swRefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/click"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click Me!"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Post your xml layout

Comment: without any code, we have absolutly no idea of what you did.

Comment: @IvanWooll I added the XML. I just replace fragments in the app

Comment: @FlorentBreton the App doesn't have any special thing. I just replace fragments

Comment: @IvanWooll FragmentA

Comment: It seems like you're replacing the fragment that contains the SwipeRefreshLayout. You can either wrap the whole containing layout in a SwipeRefreshLayout or implement one in each child fragment

Comment: You want to keep the "loading icon" appear when you press back button from fragment B???

Comment: @TaQuangTu Yes.

Comment: @IvanWooll Yes I'm replacing the fragment that contains the SwipeRefreshLayout but I want SwipeRefreshLayout to be visible after I come back to FragmentA

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this may be you should use your SwipeFreshLayout in activity's xml file which is parent to both fragments.